# C++ global includes

Tags: c++, header-files

Is there any way how include all neaded things just by one .h file ? (When I made try I get really lot of errors ...)

There is a small example of my meaning:

- Includes:

  - main.cpp -> main.h (class & vars) -> includes.h
  - test.cpp -> test.h (class & vars) -> includes.h
  - includes.h

    - iostream
    - windows.h
    - somelib.h
    - ...

Comment: Huh?  Do not understand.

Comment: Visual studio has something like "precompiled headers", that all necessary includes are included in stdafx.h. These headers are parsed and compiled just once.

Comment: These two was just examples I mean it for everything like some directx library or whatever else ...

Comment: Reminder:  if everything is in one include, anytime you make a change to the include file, *everything* is rebuilt.  To speed up the build process, only include the files you need in order to resolve symbols. In a decent build process, the compiler only compiles files whose source or include file has changed; the others are only linked, which speeds up the process.

Comment: Your example is possible, but i don´t get what´s the problem.

Comment: Also, the larger the file, the higher the probability it has defects and the more problematic in editing.

Comment: The problem is that the compiler dosn't see other libraries like if I include test.h in includes I don't see it in main.cpp...

Comment: "When I made try I get really lot of errors", what errors are they?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's very useful and avoid to circular `include` :

Soppose you  have `x.h` :
in head of `x.h`You should define :

```
#ifndef X_H
#def X_H

///CODE of x.h

#endif X_H
```

Then you should create a `includes.h` and according to dependencies , include your header files in `includes.h`

Finally: 
Every where you want to include each files you only do :

```
#include "includes.h"
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found where the problwm was. If you're using global include file it can't contain includes for sub-includes which defines class and vars.
Like if you want in main use someting from test you can't put test.h include to includes.h ...